# Netbeans lamp php interpereter not working

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, netbeans

I am following this netbean guide https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu.html#createDocumentRootLocation

But I am stuck at creating the virtual host. I try to do as in the tutorial but there is no `<Directory>` tags in the "000-default.conf" file. I kept going and ignored that.

I did as in the tutorial and put it in my /home/user/public_html. but now when I run it the php code is not interpreted

If I a2ensite the default I can access virtual host set at /var/www/html and that php is interpreted

There are no errors the php is just not being interpreted, what am I doing wrong here.

Im using:

- Ubuntu 18.10 LTS
- PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu1 (cli)
- Apache/2.4.34

Edit:
My "TestPhp.conf" file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/jelly/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit 2 and answer:

Turned out to be some lines in my "php7.2.conf" file that had to be commented out as the out-commented lines in that file explains. as running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is your test script like? if you start with `<?` try `<?php` instead.

Also check php.ini for `expose_php = false` (may hide php form the headers)

If the error persists, include your config and test script, along with any errors in http.log

You need to find a config file which enables php

I only have a Ubuntu, and the files in my installation may vary compared to yours:

**Enable PHP engine [php.load]**

This is the part that loads the PHP interpreter, and allows you to use php scripts

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

**Enable .php file directed to php  [php5.conf]**

This is the part tells apache to send *.php (and in this case some other extensions like *.phtml) to the php interpreter

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    # Deny access to raw php sources by default
    # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
    # only in specific virtual host or directory
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
# Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml|ps)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

**EDIT** I noticed that you were on UBUNTU as well

use `sudo a2enmod` and select php in the list

**EDIT 2**

Note that if you are following a general Guide and not a UBUNTU specific one, you may encounter several issues since the UBUNTU apache config is spread out in several files, as opposed to one big file, which is what you may encounter in other distros

Comment: my php test is like this `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`  php.ini has `expose_php = On`  i will edit my first comment with the config file now. I am not sure of the convension here as im not used to stackoverflow, when there is alot of information do i edit my main question or do i do it in answer my own question? also were do i find my http.log

Comment: you may get a warning if you include too much code/logfiles, but if you have a well formulated question, where the code and logs backs it up there is no issue.

Comment: I cannot find any http.log file. I have edited my answer with the conf file

Comment: see my edit. your logs are in `/var/logs/apache2` and you need to be root to read them and you will need to look in error.log

Comment: I found the php5.conf (in my chase 7.2) and there were these out commented lines "Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default" and it simply told me to uncomment the next cuple of lines. now every thing works, thank you very much! I don't know how i would have found that out on my own

Comment: Super i gather that you got everything working. Good that you also updated your question with your findings.